# Check if array is rotated method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to see if arr1 is a rotated version of arr2. I know there might be a more efficient version, but my program isn't even printing or returning an error. It just keeps running. Could someone say why my program isn't even returning anything?

```
 class Rotated {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr1 = {1,4,8,6,10};
    int[] arr2 = {8,6,10,1,4};
    boolean b= rotated(arr1, arr2);
    System.out.println(b);

  }

   static boolean rotated(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){

    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){

      for(int j=0; j< arr2.length; j++){

        if(arr1[i]== arr2[j]){

          count++;
        }

        else if(arr2[j+1] >= arr2.length){

          j=0;

        }

        else if(arr1[i]!=arr2[j]){

          count =0;

        }

      }
    }

    return count == arr1.length;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking to see if a value in the array is greater than the length of the array?  Why, if this is true, are you resetting the loop index?

Comment: I now realized that is wrong. I wanted to say if the j index goes out of bounds then go back to the first index, so set j =0, so that I can check if the rest of the numbers in arr2 match arr1.

Answer (score 3):

You were not very clear on what "rotated" means so I wrote out 2 methods for you. This is the most efficient way for either definition of rotated.

This method assumes rotated means inverted (index of elements are switched, first becomes last, last becomes first, ect.)

```
public boolean rotated(int[] a, int[] b){
    if (a.size()!=b.size())return false;
    for(int i=0; 1<a.size(); i++){
        if(a[i]!=b[a.size()-i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This method assumes rotated means jumbled (the elements are all there just in a different order)

You need to type `import java.util.Arrays;' in the beginning for this to work

```
public boolean rotated(int[] a, int[] b){
    if (a.size()!=b.size())return false;
    for(int i=0; 1<a.size(); i++){
        if(!b.contains(a[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I hope this helps, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

when you have j=4, then in your code
 j=0; changes j=4 -> j=0

and the loop is going on ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(arr2[j+1] >= arr2.length){

      j=0;

    }
```

is your problem. You compare the element of an array with the array length! Do not reset the loop variable within the loop, this produce the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your approach here, and you made some mistakes in accessing arr2[j+1] this can throw IndexOutOfBounds exception and you reset your index j if an element in the arr2 is greater than the length of the array this may lead to infinite loop

Here's a simple program that check for rotation

```
static boolean rotated(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    boolean isRotation = false;
    int len = arr1.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < len && !isRotation; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < len && !isRotation; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) { //We beign our check for rotation
                int k = (i + 1) % len;
                int l = (j + 1) % len;

                while (k != i && arr1[k] == arr2[l]) {
                    k = (k + 1) % len;
                    l = (l + 1) % len;
                }

                if (k == i) {
                    isRotation = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return isRotation;
}
```